# how to get elements in "div id=0" using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I have downloaded and included [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/) but when I try to get data from `<div id='0'>` it just gets data from every div id.

`$html_data=$htmlfile->find('div[id=0]',0);`

but if I used `div[id=1]` , it works perfectly .

any ideas ?

`<div id=0>data0 </div>`

`<div id=1>data1 </div>`

`<div id=2>data2 </div>`

`<div id=3>data3 </div>`

html file is like above , I need to get `data0` using `find('div[id=0]',0)` it is not working but if I type `find('div[id=1]',0)` I can get `data1` without a problem.

**NOTE**

I have other `div id=idname` files in the html as well .

Answer (score 0):

Assuimg extra `('div[id=0]',0)` , `0` here in .. you may be selecting the first element.

```
$html_data=$htmlfile->find('div[id=0]',0);
```

So , instead use ..

```
$html_data=$htmlfile->find('div[id=0]')[0];
```

to get the first element.

Comment: I have this html file with , <div id=0>data1</div>   & <div id=1>data2</div> I need to get "data1" I tried your code but it didn't work

Comment: I explained in the question , please take a look thank you